# Building an API, beside a (React/Firebase) web app

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-router

I have a web app using React and Firebase Realtime Database.

The *index.js* file looks like the following:

```
import React from 'react';
import { userInfo } from 'os'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
.....


class RouterBlock extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      logdInSatus: false
    };
  }

  .....

  render() {
    .....
    return (
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" element={<TopMenu/>} />
          .....
          <Route exact path="/p1" element={<Component_1/>} />
          <Route exact path="/p2" element={<Component_2/>} />
          <Route exact path="/p3" element={<Component_3/>} />
          .....
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    );
  }
```

}

It all works pretty much the way I wish.

From this point, here is what I want:

An API for a customer, which is going to allow him to get data from my DB for his own use.

My app is now accessible through a URL like:
https://example.com/myWebApp

The API for the customer(s) should be used via this:
https://example.com/myAPI
and it would return JSON data from my DB that the customer can then use.

The top file for the API would probably look something like (but I am not yet sure):

```
const http = require("http")
import { getDatabase, ref, onValue} from "firebase/database";
import { url } from 'inspector'
import { workerData } from 'worker_threads'
const db = getDatabase();

.....

const requestListener = function (req, res) {
    res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
    res.writeHead(200)
    res.end(`{"message": "This is a JSON response"}`)
    // Here data needs to be taken from the actual DB.
}

const server = http.createServer(requestListener)
server.listen(port, host, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on http://${host}:${port}`)
})
```

Finally, my question is about the routing for the API url. Should it be one of the routes found in index.js or something totally separated? If this is the case (a route inside index.js), what is the proper syntax that I should use for this route? What I tried did not work.
Since all my current routes use a React component, I suppose this one needs to be different, but I don't know how to handle it. Any relevant hint will be welcome.

Comment: Backend APIs are defined in the backend, they don't have much of anything to do what any frontend app might be doing or rendering. What exactly is your question/issue?

Comment: @Drew Reese. Do you mean that the API I want to make for the customer should be a totally different app ?

Comment: Essentially, yes. It sounds like your question is about where, or how, to create the backend.

Comment: OK in that case, you are probably right. Where and how should I create it then? Or at least how can I get started?

Comment: It looks like you have started with some Express code. Just to clarify my comments, *a* server can host your frontend app code ***and*** backend services, so you'll want to "namespace" them, like your `"/myWebApp"` and `"/myAPI"`, which is part of what you might've been asking about.

Comment: For the time being I have a React app working on Firebase. I am not sure what you are referring to when you mention "some Express code".

Comment: Any reason for not using the Firebase JS SDK?

Comment: Well, no. Do you recommend using it for my use case? If yes, is there a good tutorial somewhere?

Comment: I am already using "firebase deploy". Is this part of what you call "Firebase JS SDK" ?

Comment: I was referring to the second snippet of code, it *looks* like express.js/node.js code, i.e. backend API code, handling requests.

Comment: @Drew Reese. Oh, I see. In fact the first snippet of code is what is already working the second one is only "fiction code" it is what I think is probably necessary to do what I want (without being sure). It is not yet implemented.